# Accessing container on bridge network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have 2 docker-compose files

1:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.6

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

2:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  api:
    image: myapi:1

networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true
```

But inside the `api` container, the hostname `database` is not found. I have also tried `mynetwork_database` but that is also not found

How do I access a container on an external network?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add:

```
networks:
  <mysql_project_folder_name>_mynetwork:
    external: true
```

And:

```
networks:
  - <mysql_project_folder_name>_mynetwork
```

to `api` service